# How to do Receipt printing using codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I would like my codenameone based android application to print receipts using a rego bluetooth printer. Is there any plugin / extension that is able to do this or i might have to go the cnlib route

Comment: @javalove answer is correct and I know some people use bluetooth. But I'd do something much simpler. I'd just generate HTML or PDF and do an `execute` on the file. This will launch a native browser, PDF viewer etc. The cool part is that you can then use the native print functionality of those apps and you'd get a preview for free.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bluetooth extension for codenameone since 2016. I am not sure if it has been updated, but you can check it out here https://www.codenameone.com/blog/bluetooth-support.html It gives a small test code to get started. Search for the CNIBluetooth extension, add it to your project then refresh libs.

```
final Bluetooth bt = new Bluetooth();
        Form main = new Form("Bluetooth Demo");
        main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        main.add(new Button(new Command("enable bluetooth") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                try {
                    if (!bt.isEnabled()) {
                        bt.enable();
                    }
                    if (!bt.hasPermission()) {
                        bt.requestPermission();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));
        main.add(new Button(new Command("initialize") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                try {
                    bt.initialize(true, false, "bluetoothleplugin");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));
```